# Period can be matched but not used

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a problem with a marker. I enter in a word with a period and it can match if it is in there (Example is `Filters.`) but when it goes through the mark function, it does not work. Here is the code:

```
function Search () {
var Notes = document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML;
var i = document.getElementById("Bar").value;
var inputReOne = $.trim(i);
var inp = inputReOne.replace(".", "\.")
    if ($.trim(inp) !== '') {
        var InpComp = inp.toUpperCase();
        var Ind = tags.indexOf(InpComp);
        if (Ind === -1) {
            var inpReg = new RegExp(inp, "im");
            var WordCheck = Notes.match(inpReg);
            alert(WordCheck)
            if(WordCheck !== null) {
            tags.push(InpComp);
            var SearchReq = new RegExp("\\b(" + inp + ")\\b", "gim");
            var after = Notes.replace(SearchReq, "<mark class=" + ColorOptionReady + ">$1</mark>");
            document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML = after;
}
```

`WordCheck` matches `Filters.` but when it runs through the rest of the function, it doesn't add `<mark class=ColorOptionReady (A variable)>Filters.</mark>`

It just leaves it with no mark tags. Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you need to change `"\."` into `"\\."` in line `var inp = inputReOne.replace(".", "\.")`. Don't think you need the `toUpperCase` checks, if you're using `i` modifier. And I guess you'd need to check for all possible Regexp meta characters, not only `.`. Which in turn makes me think you're trying to achieve some result that might be solved way simpler if approached differently. But I don't know the underlying problem from your question ;)

Comment: I don't understand why I need to change "\." to "\\." It doesn't work for me. It just returns `Filters\.`

Comment: okay, you might not really need it - but you did the same for `\\b` in your second RegExp, which is different to the one you match against in `WordCheck`. As a regular dot is a word boundary, the `\b` won't see another boundary, I guess.

Comment: What would be a way of marking a "."? I thought of using `\s` but that didn't work either.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need the extra check for word boundaries around the regular expression? If I think of `Notes` being `'Hello Filters. Foo'`, it would match against `var SearchReq = new RegExp("\\b("+inp+")\\s", "gim");`

Comment: I added the \b to be able to only mark full words or a string of words not just 'filt' in 'filter'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105566/discussion-between-narigo-and-hawkeye).